# Check the invertibility of a matrix given a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find all values of $c$, if any, for which the given matrix is invertible (using row operations -> gotta try simplifying to I).

Here is the matrix : 
\begin{pmatrix}c&1&0\\1&c&1\\0&1&c\end{pmatrix}

Comment: using row ops. im not sure when i can make assumptions about which numbers are not allowed when i do that. thanks for edit and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R_1,R_2,R_3$ are the first, second and third row

Let's assume that $c\neq0$
, as the case $c=0$ is very simple.

$\begin{pmatrix}c&1&0\\1&c&1\\0&1&c\end{pmatrix}$ $R_1\leftarrow \frac{R_1}c$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&1/c&0\\1&c&1\\0&1&c\end{pmatrix}$ $R_2\leftarrow R_2-R_1$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&1/c&0\\0&c-1/c&1\\0&1&c\end{pmatrix}$ $R_2\leftarrow R_2\cdot\frac{c}{c^2-1}$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&1/c&0\\0&1&\frac{c}{c^2-1}\\0&1&c\end{pmatrix}$ $R_3\leftarrow R_3-R_2$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&1/c&0\\0&1&\frac{c}{c^2-1}\\0&0&c-\frac{c}{c^2-1}\end{pmatrix}$ $R_1\leftarrow R_1-c\cdot R_2$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\frac{c^2}{c^2-1}\\0&1&\frac{c}{c^2-1}\\0&0&\frac{c^3-2c}{c^2-1}\end{pmatrix}$

Can you do the last two steps by yourself ? :) :) :)

Comment: Awesome :) so its as i thought u do it as u usually do and then deduct the parameters from there. i was thinking that there are ways without restricting urself to certain parameters and therefore u have to go by those ways but it seems that the rules are simple from what u r showing me. k

Comment: so u r sure u r doing it right by simply pursuing it as is?

Comment: This way works @Newton

Comment: awesome. thanks a lot

Comment: note that technically, you need to consider the case c=0 if you're going to use this method, as the above logic fails if it was (You'd be dividing by 0 at the first couple of steps).

Comment: @Alan Thanks for noticing. That being said, the case $c=0$ is trivial.

Comment: @TheGame Agreed, it's trivial, thus why I said 'technically' :). Still needs to be done for a formal proof

Comment: - yep - so r u saying that u can simplify it down however u feel like?

Comment: @Newton What do you mean ?

Comment: because for ex sometimes u can avoid restricting 0 maybe when u do it

Comment: What are the last 2 steps? Should you continue to put it into reduced row echelon form? How do you get an expression for C?

Answer (score -2):

Find the determinant of this matrix and notice where it becomes zero. The matrix is invertible for every value except those.

Comment: i guess i can use that to determine the rules but as i said using row ops not determinants .